# Mono can't save user settings

Tags: c#, mono, settings

I have problems with saving user settings on Mono (Ubuntu). Here is code sample:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string savedText = Properties.Settings.Default.tbText.ToString();
    tbInput.Text = savedText;
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    string textToSave = tbInput.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.tbText = textToSave;
    Properties.Settings.Default.tbText = Properties.Settings.Default.tbText;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

But i receive only empty config like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <userSettings />
</configuration>
```

I've already tried something like

```
Properties.Settings.Default.tbText = Properties.Settings.Default.tbText;
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583606/mono-doesnt-write-settings-defaults). But still get same result. How can I use settings in Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove line

   ```
   Properties.Settings.Default.tbText = Properties.Settings.Default.tbText;
   ```
2. Check you application config file. Probably you have something like this:

   ```
   <configuration>
     <configSections>
       <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
                     type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
         <section name="ExampleApp.Properties.Settings" 
                  type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
       </sectionGroup>
     </configSections>
     ...
     <appSettings>
       <add key="TestKey1" value="Test1" />
       <add key="TestKey2" value="Test2" />
     </appSettings>
     ...
     <userSettings>
       <ExampleApp.Properties.Settings>
         <setting name="textBox1" serializeAs="String">
           <value />
         </setting>
       </ExampleApp.Properties.Settings>
     </userSettings>
   </configuration>
   ```

   Remove sectionGroup for **userSettings**.

   ```
   <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
                 type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
       <section name="ExampleApp.Properties.Settings" 
                type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
   </sectionGroup>
   ```

   Remove also section **userSettings**.

   ```
   <userSettings>
     ...
   </userSettings>
   ```
3. Delete your local **user.config**. After first run it will be recreated correctly.

   It should work

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I'd expect that all the settings should remain usable. When removing all these sections, they won't be usable any more, will they?

Comment: I am guilty of downvoting too soon. This solution DID work for me!
I had trouble hunting down the user.config file (eventually found it in ~/.local/share). It would be nice to know why/how this works...

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with this, and PiKos advice didn't work for me. Mine was just as you found:

I had an AppName.exe.config alongside my AppName.exe, and this had data like:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="AppName.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <userSettings>
    <AppName.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="X" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
    </AppName.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

I had an `~/.local/share/CompanyName/AppName_4309857324572934859834/user.config` that as effectively empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <userSettings />
</configuration>
```

Note that this `sectionGroup` has no children but the one in `AppName.exe.config` did

The solution for me was to cut the relevant `<sectiongroup>` plus its child, and also `<userSettings>` out of `AppName.exe.config` and paste them into the empty `user.config`

---

It seems that mono expects them to be in only one place. If they're in `appname.exe.cofnig` you'll get an empty user.config written. If they're in user.config they will be updated there when Save() is called. The down side of this, I think, is that if user.config ever gets damaged, there isn't any default settings anywhere (I tried PiKos' advice to delete them from `AppName.exe.config` and also delete user.config then relauncht he app; user.config was created with all the settings names, but all the values were null)